# How to return to camera when looking at Albums?

Tags: camera

I've noticed that in iOS 8 (I think in 7 too), you can't seem to get back to the camera to take another picture, when looking at albums/photos.

For example:

1. Launch camera
2. Tap small photo icon in lower left corner to view latest photos taken
3. Tap All Photos in upper left
4. Now you can't get back to camera to take another photo

The only way to return seems to be to click Home to return to the home screen, then launch the camera app again.  Is this so?  Is there no simpler way to just get back into the camera mode you were just in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. This is because it is switching from the Camera app to the Photos app. People have been a little annoyed with this for a long time, but I suppose the separation is logical.

To get back to the camera you can either:

1. Double tap the home button and swipe from right to left and then tap the camera app, or
2. Swipe up from the bottom of the screen and tap the camera icon in the Control Center.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's logical... kinda... in theory... on paper.  LOL  But in actual practice, one of the most common things someone would want to do, would be to look at their photos, then take some more.  Oh well... just using the application switcher works.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I'm sure it is something that they hashed out at Apple HQ. There has been the separation since the original iPhone, I believe. Perhaps it facilitates faster loading? Also, I suppose it works from the standpoint that one doesn't have to open the camera just to look at pictures. But, then again, it's just my musings as I don't think we have an explanation from Apple.